# React.js - array is undefined even when I defined it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I define array and in debugger and in app it is always undefined.
I have no way how to debug this, simply javascript is not working as it should..

```
let newArray=[];
for (let i in data) {    ///newArray is undefined
   const newData = update(data[i],
       reactID: {$set: this.reactID}
   });
   newArray.push(newData);  ///newArray is undefined
   this.reactID++;
}
dispatch(actions.change("model.records",newArray)); ///newArray is undefined
```

Even debugging dispatch and redux action , newArray is also there undefined...

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

After 1 hours of debugging , rebuilding with webpack I renamed "newArray" to "something" and now after some magic happend it is working.
And no I do not have anywhere in function defined "newArray" I tripple checked using find ;)